# UWP display Image from external path?

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to port a simple WPF program to UWP. It is a tool for applying some custom image analysis routines to a bunch of images.

Basic functionality:

1. Add images to a gallery view (could be 100,000 images)
2. Run analysis on images
3. Export data

The problem I'm having is displaying the images in a gallery.

In WPF I could make a `ListBox` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `InputImage` like `<Image Source={Binding Image, IsAsync=True} />`

```
public class InputImage
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public BitmapImage Source
    {
        get
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Path, UriKind.Absolute));
            image.Freeze();
            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent in UWP?

- I have tried the above (minus the `IsAsync` and `Freeze` parts) but the image has width and height 0.
- I thought perhaps I will have to create a `StorageFile` from the path, open that and set the bitmap source, but I can't use `async` methods inside the property getter...

Any solutions?

Note: I have broadFileSystemAccess" enabled in the appxmanifest and turned on for the app in Settings -> Privacy -> File System

Comment: Hi, you can bind the Source of in Image in your listview to a string containing the uri. no need to create a BitmapImagesource

Comment: @thezapper That was my first approach using the `file:///` style URI, but it didn't work in UWP, just a blank image. (I'm actually using a GridView but that probably doesn't matter). If the URI is to something within the assembly (e.g. Assets/….) it works, but not outside.

Comment: May your Image size is zip.

Comment: @lindexi solved it - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, here is what I learnt:

Even with `broadFileSystemAccess` enabled, external files seem to have to be accessed via a `StorageFile`. e.g.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\path\to\file");
```

You can instantiate the `BitmapImage` property and bind directly to that when you first load the list of images, e.g.

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
InputImage.Source = image;
```

This is fine for a single image but with 1000's of images there is a problem - each image is loaded, taking significant time and memory, even with the virtualising aspects of GridView and other controls.

The solution was to use an async binding (yes it seems this is actually possible) as described on [Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

Procedure:

Install the `Nito.AsyncEx` NuGet package.

Use the following for the property:

```
    public INotifyTaskCompletion<BitmapImage> ImageAsync
    {
        get { return NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(GetImageAsync()); }
    }

    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageAsync()
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path);
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Then bind the image as the result of this task, noting to use `Binding` and not `x:Bind`:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageAsync.Result}"/>
```

Comment: But your image can not update when the Path changed.

Comment: @lindexi That isn't a problem for me, but I guess if the path changed you could fire a property changed event for ImageAsync from the path setter.